# How to represent a missing xsd:dateTime in RDF?

Tags: xsd, rdf

I have a dataset with data collected from a form that contains various date and value fields. Not all fields are mandatory so blanks are possible and 
in many cases expected, like a `DeathDate` field for a patient who is still alive.

How do I best represent these blanks in the data?

I represent `DeathDate` using `xsd:dateTime`. Blanks or empty spaces are not allowed. All of these are flagged as invalid when validating using Jena RIOT:

```
foo:DeathDate_1
    a foo:Deathdate ;
    time:inXSDDatetime  " "^^xsd:dateTime .

foo:DeathDate_2
    a                   foo:Deathdate ;
    time:inXSDDatetime  ""^^xsd:dateTime .

foo:DeathDate_3
    a                   foo:Deathdate ;
    time:inXSDDatetime  "--"^^xsd:dateTime .
```

I prefer to not omit the triple because I need to know if it was blank on the source versus a conversion error during construction of my RDF.

What is the best way to code these missing values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should represent this by just omitting the triple. That's the *meaning* of a triple that's "not present": it's information that is (currently) unknown.

Alternatively, you can choose to give it the value `"unknown"^^xsd:string` when there's no death date. The solution in this case is to not datatype it as an `xsd:dateTime`, but just as a simple string. It doesn't have to be a string of course, you could use any kind of "special" value for this, e.g. a boolean `false` - just as long as it's a valid literal value that you can distinguish from *actual* death dates. This will solve the parsing problem, but IMHO if you do this, you are setting yourself up for headaches in processing the data further down the line (because you will need to ask queries over this data, and they will have to take two different types of values into account, *plus* the possibility that the field is missing).

> I prefer to not omit the triple because I need to know if it was blank
>   on the source versus a conversion error during construction of my RDF.

This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If there are conversion errors, your application should signal that in another way, e.g. by logging an error. You shouldn't try to solve this by "corrupting" your data.

Comment: Thanks, Jeen. It makes good sense to omit the triple as you suggest. I will code my conversion process (scripted in R) to catch errors during conversion rather than code them into the resulting RDF.   I agree the solution is not to fabricate/corrupt data during conversion. If I face a requirement to identify different types of missing I will likely code it using addition triples.